# How can I find my awk version?

Tags: awk

If I want to know the version of awk I get the following:

```
$ awk --version
awk: not an option: --version
```

Checking in `man awk` I see that my awk is

> mawk - pattern scanning and text processing language

Comment: --version is something the GNU invented for their own commands, it is not part of POSIX and most commands don't support --version. GNU awk does however, and awk --version does something sensible on my system. fedorqui's distribution uses something other than GNU awk by default.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner that's an interesting information you gave. Thanks! My awk is `mawk`, hence the inexistence of `version`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, `man awk` shows us:

> -W version
>
> mawk writes its version and copyright to stdout and compiled limits to
>   stderr and exits 0.

In my case,

```
$ awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
```

Comment: my version is showing 2020 January and it still wouldn't support `-v` or `--version` on Linux. On the Mac, it is showing a 2007 version but it supports `--version`. I suppose `awk` is important enough that they can do whatever they want, and it is coherent with what I feel at work: if you are easy, you get looked down and stepped on. If you are difficult, you get respected

Comment: @nonopolarity what Awk are you using?

Comment: I check my Big Sur (on M1) again, and it showed `20200816` The one that showed 2007 was Mojave.  The one that needed the `-W` was showing `mawk`

Answer (score 6):

I try to be more general.

`awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null || awk --version`

works whether awk invokes mawk, gawk or original-awk available for Debian/Ubuntu Linux. Note that `-W` and `version` have to be concatenated so that original-awk does not think `version` is a program.
In Ubuntu Linux you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config awk` to see and to choose the implementation that is invoked by the command awk.

Comment: I don't know how standard it is to accept the concatenated option, but it is not necessary use it in my experience: `awk -W version </dev/null 2>/dev/null|awk '{print $0;nz=1}END{if(!nz)exit 1}' || awk --version` or alternatively `(s=$(awk -W version </dev/null 2>/dev/null); if [ -n "$s" ]; then printf "$s\n"; else awk --version; fi)`